# Deprecated warning in AWS EB version recommended to upgrade to same version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8

I have a deprecation warning in my ElasticBeanstalk environments, but when I go to change the platform, the current version of the platform and the recommended one are the same, so I don't know how to remove the deprecation warning.

[Deprecation warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUBtf.png)

[Upgrade version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99wnr.png)

The environments are running Java 8 on 64bit Amazon Linux 2.11.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current platform is `Java 8 on 64bit Amazon Linux 2.11.9`, [made deprecated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-retiring.html#platforms-retiring.javase) at the end of June 2021. What's more this is Amazon Linux 1 (AL1) platform. The [current versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.javase) are only based on AL2:

- 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.2.2 running Corretto 11
- 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v4.2.2 running Tomcat 8.5 Corretto 11

Sadly, there is **no automated** migration from AL1 to AL2. There is too much braking changes between the two. You have to **manually port** your app to AL2 based EB platforms as described in:

- [Migrating your Elastic Beanstalk Linux application to Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)