# Upgrade an elasticbeanstalk platform from 3.6 to 3.7 Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

I have an existing AWS elastic beanstalk flask application that deploys from circleci.  The application is a python app, and has been running fine under AWS EB platform, "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.10 running Python 3.6".  This platform is deprecated.

I want to update this platform from the command line.  My (possibly errant) thinking is that I should be able to do this by modifying the local `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml`, which was created via `eb init` and is how I deploy the app (via `eb deploy`.  My attempt at modifying the config.yml file looks like this:

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: env-name

global:
  application_name: app-name
  default_ec2_keyname: keyname
  default_platform: Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
  default_region: us-east-2
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: null
```

But this does not change the existing environment.  Might be because i set the `global.default_platform` to something new and ... of course, this is NOT a new env, but one that I want to update.  Is there a way to set the platform that must be used for this EB app?  Do I need to delete the original env to do the update?  Is there any reference guide for this file (I could not find one)?
Thx for any pointers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deprecated warning in AWS EB version recommended to upgrade to same version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68405223/deprecated-warning-in-aws-eb-version-recommended-to-upgrade-to-same-version)

Comment: Hi @TylerH, thanks for the reply, but no, this is a different issue.

Comment: The answer that Marcin posted here (which was deleted by a moderator) has the exact same content as the answer they posted to the question I linked above, so despite the different title and question, I *suspect* the answer may actually apply here as well. Namely the link to manually migrate your application to AL2 and the disclaimer that there is no automated migration available for Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Marcin's answer was not appropriate for that question, but you're right, it probably is appropriate here. If somebody wants to post it here, I'd accept as the answer.